# How to fill a pandas column by calculation involving values from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by

I got two dataframes, one (`baseDataframe`) keeps some base data for every individual `n`

```
      n       date1   age
0  1135  2021-05-08  <NA>
1  1339  2021-08-02  <NA>
2  1456  2021-08-07  <NA>
3  5765  2021-01-02  <NA>
4  6566  2021-05-12  <NA>
5  7756  2021-06-22  <NA>
```

and a second dataframe (`actionDataframe`) that keeps data for every action of those individuals `n`

```
       n  actionID action1date
0   1135         1  2022-04-01
1   1135         2  2022-06-11
2   1135         3  2022-08-04
3   1339         1  2022-05-03
4   1339         2  2022-07-21
5   1456         1  2022-08-07
6   1456         2  2022-09-30
7   1456         3  2022-11-11
8   1456         4  2023-01-12
9   5765         1  2022-04-22
10  5765         2  2022-06-11
11  6566         1  2022-04-02
12  7756         1  2022-12-12
13  7756         2  2023-02-01
```

now I want to fill the `age` column of the `baseDataframe` by getting the `action1date` of the lowest `actionID` for each `n` from the `actionDataframe` and subtract the `date1` from `baseDataframe` from it.

I got all of it working with a for-loop before (gonna skip the code for that one).

```py
for n in baseDataframe.index
# calculations here
```

but now I read that iterating over dataframes is bad practice and slow. Now I'm wondering if there are other options to do something a bit more complex like the task I'm trying to do with built-in functions. I just can't find the right keywords to google and look up.

The end result I'm looking for:

```
      n       date1  age
0  1135  2021-05-08  328
1  1339  2021-08-02  274
2  1456  2021-08-07  365
3  5765  2021-01-02  475
4  6566  2021-05-12  325
5  7756  2021-06-22  538
```

How do I do it without an explicit loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way where for each `n`, the indices of the lowest `actionID` (which is found using `groupby.idxmin`) is used to filter the corresponding `action1date` values, which are in turn mapped to their baseDataFrame `n` values and the time difference is computed. The desired column `age` is the time difference in days. Note that if the datetime columns are already `datetime64[ns]` dtype, then there's no need to convert to datetime again.

```py
lowest_actionID_per_n = actionDataframe.groupby('n')['actionID'].idxmin()
action_dates = actionDataframe.loc[lowest_actionID_per_n, ['n', 'action1date']].set_index('n').squeeze()
baseDataframe['age'] = (pd.to_datetime(baseDataframe['n'].map(action_dates)) - pd.to_datetime(baseDataframe['date1'])).dt.days
```

[image: result]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255856/discussion-between-cottontail-and-t3ahunt3r).